# click once application uninstall

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, clickonce

does anyone know if there is a way to uninstall a click once application upon the install of a new one?

We have software 2.0 and are going to be deploying 3.0, which is a completely new windows application.

Is there a way in the settings or code to say upon the install of 3.0 uninstall 2.0?

Comment: No. Every CO installation is in a "sandbox" and it does not interact with the others. So version 2 and version 3 are like 2 differents app. You can insert a routine to delete the old version in the newer app but keep in mind clickonce setup's directory change between pc/installations.

Answer (score 1):

In your new application, search `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for the subkey corresponding to your old application (e.g. comparing the `DisplayName`). From this subkey, extract the `UninstallString` and run it.

Notice, however, that this is not a completely silent uninstall. It will ask the user to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

That is the purpose of `click once` - version updating.
 you dont have to determine the version number and you can publish updates to the production project, you can deploy the updates to network directory, ftp site, or website server.
 basically after you deploy a new version to the project each user gets the new updates (exe, dll`s etc..).

> The application is added to the user's Start menu and to the Add or
>   Remove Programs group in the Control Panel. Unlike other deployment
>   technologies, nothing is added to the Program Files folder, the
>   registry, or the desktop, and no administrative rights are required
>   for installation When the application developer creates an updated
>   version of the application, he or she also generates a new application
>   manifest and copies files to a deployment location—usually a sibling
>   folder to the original application deployment folder. The
>   administrator updates the deployment manifest to point to the location
>   of the new version of the application.

`click once` is very friendly and effective platform.
 you should read more about it, start here: [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Another thing that is not directly connected to this topic but i find it important mention is that you can create setup files to install your software in distant stations that can not get "automatic updates" from click once using [Windows Installer Package (.msi)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978328.aspx)

Comment: im not sure if i asked my question correctly, if i currently have a deployed windows application and i want to make a completely new application (ie: go to visual studio and create new)... then when i deploy the new application i want to uninstall the old one... i think mentioning versions might have made it more confusing. I am familiar with versioning the same windows application.

Comment: @ user7668852 I think you will have to use windows scripting if all the users are on local network...click once can not register a new application.